# My Guessing game isn't able to print out the dialogue

Tags: python, random

beginner here!
My question is, why doesn't the terminal say the prints?

```
import random
print(" Guess number between 1-5")
def Guessinggame(Number = int(random.randint(1, 5))):
    if input == Number:
        return "YOU'RE AWESOME!"
    else:
        return "Not correct"        
while():
    Guessinggame()
```

It's a guessing game where you have to guess between the number 1 and 5.

Comment: I don't see any print statements (apart from "Guess the number...") or attempts to acquire input data. Also, the Guessinggame function will never be invoked because while(): is effectively a noop

Comment: I think that `while():` is equivalent to: `while tuple():` which is equivalent to `while False:` so you end up never calling `Guessinggame()`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, what exactly do you expect `while():` to mean? In your own words, what are the `()` for, and why have you written them there? In your own words, what is the intended logical condition for continuing vs. exiting the loop?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```py
import random

def Guessinggame(inp):
    Number = random.randint(1, 5)
    print(inp,Number)
    if inp == Number:
        return "YOU'RE AWESOME!"
    else:
        return "Not correct" 

while True:
    inp=int(input("Guess number between 1-5"))
    print(Guessinggame(inp))
```

Here what we are doing is, program starts from while loop. The correct way to use while loop is `while <condition>`, if you are doing `while()` then it is calling while function. After infinitely `while` loop start, we are asking user to input number and we are saving that number in `inp` variable. Now we are sending inp variable into `Guessinggame` function. Inside this we are creating new variable `number` which is random number. And now we are checking if user input  number same to random number or not. And return `YOU'RE AWESOME` is true and return `Not correct` if false. And that return will be printed because we are calling function inside print.

Answer (score 1):

`return` will only return the value, not **print** it. You need to call the print function to print the value.

```
print(Guessinggame())
```

Also, your program has some logical error it should be

```
import random
print(" Guess number between 1-5")
def Guessinggame(guess,Number):
    if guess== Number:
        return "YOU'RE AWESOME!"
    else:
        return "Not correct"        
while True:
    y=int(input("enter a number: "))
    x= int(random.randint(1, 5))
    print(Guessinggame(y,x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your guessing game function is returning either "YOU'RE AWESOME" or "Not correct", but there is no print statement included. To demonstrate what's going on, we could include an extra variable in your code:

```
import random

def Guessinggame():
    # I've added in an input function to get the user input
    user_input = input(" Guess number between 1-5")
    Number = int(random.randint(1, 5)) # more readable here

    if user_input == Number:
        return "YOU'RE AWESOME!"
    else:
        return "Not correct"   
     
while True:
    outcome = Guessinggame() 
    print(outcome)
```

Now "YOU'RE AWESOME!" or "Not correct" gets stored inside of the `outcome` variable. Printing `outcome` will show the result. Note that you can cut out the `outcome` variable completely by printing `Guessinggame()`, I just wanted to show you what's happening.

Note that you'll also need to convert `Number` from an integer to string-type to compare it with the user input (user input is stored as string):

```
import random

def Guessinggame():
    # I've added in an input function to get the user input
    user_input = input(" Guess number between 1-5")
    Number = str(random.randint(1, 5)) # convert to string-type

    if user_input == Number:
        return "YOU'RE AWESOME!"
    else:
        return "Not correct"   
     
while True:
    outcome = Guessinggame() 
    print(outcome)
```

For more on type conversion, you check out this article I posted on LearnDataSci:

https://www.learndatasci.com/solutions/python-typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-not-str/

Comment: There's a section there which covers converting user input to integer-type, similarly to what Sujay has done in his answer. The answer on its own solves the problem, the link is just there as supplementary content for anyone who's interested!